# XML iteration issues (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

To set the scene, I'm currently working on an XML adapter for Android that will read in the XML files I've been given and parse them into a database. I thought I had this down until they sprung on me that the nodes in the XML file could change from file to file, and so I need to build in a mechanism to cope with missing variables.

The most obvious solution to this was a `switch()` statement, but that won't work with strings, so I started building an `if-then-else` structure. The idea was that it would check the name of the node and work out what to do with it based on that. Simple, no?

The problem is, I can't seem to pull the name of the nodes I need from the XML file no matter what I do. The structure of the XML file is below:

```
<Vehicle>
    <Detail>
        <VIN>BBB2791276393</VIN>
        <RegNo>KN05EAP</RegNo>
        <Doors>5</Doors>
    </Detail>
</Vehicle>
```

What I need to be able to compare against is tag names like "VIN" or "RegNo", but I can't figure out a way to pull them out. ETA: As I didn't make this clear, the child nodes of Detail change between XML files, and I have to deal with them as they come...

I'm using a DOM parser, and pulling out a `NodeList` based on `<Detail>`. `NodeList.item(0)` gives me the `<Detail>` node, but if I then try and break that down (with `getChildNodes()` for example), I can't get the tag names for `<VIN>` or `<RegNo>`. In fact, I can't seem to get any kind of reference for them that I could use to determine what node it is based on the original name.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to use SAX parser which is more efficient and recommended. Use this link , It might help you http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..as you explained that you can reach up to Detail tag..try doing it this way...

```
// Getting VIN of Detail
 if (element.getElementsByTagName("VIN").getLength() > 0) {
        childNode = element.getElementsByTagName("VIN").item(0); //Get all the elements one by one
        String VIN = childNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

    }
```

You can do it for all the children tags of Detail...Hope this will help you..!!!

Comment: The children tags of Detail will and do change between XML files. Thus grabbing a list of each one isn't the ideal solution. It's the hack I've put together (with a if NodeList !empty catch), but it's not exactly neat.

Comment: Yes, that would be an ideal solution...I assumed children nodes to be same all the time...

Answer (score 0):

Names of child nodes:

```
Element elem = (Element)nodeList.item(0);

        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
                if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                   for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                       if( child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE  ){
                           Log.i("fff", child.getNodeName());
                       }
                }
            }
        }
```

To get value of a node I use this getValue() method (I forgot where I found this solution so sadly I can't give credit to the person who made it):

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                        //child.getNodeName();
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `getNodeName()` has just been returning null when I've tried it.

Comment: Do you get details node by >>> NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Details"); <<< or do you use some other method? Does >>> Element elem = (Element)nodeList.item(0); elem.getNodeName();<<< return "Details"? Is your document normalized? >>> doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();<<<